# Do I need to learn any more programming language?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, programming-languages

As a web programmer do I need to learn any more languages to enhance my career? I work in a .NET environment and am good at C#, but have zero skill in VB. For client side scripting I use javascript, jQuery and PrototypeJS.

Should I learn any more languages or do you think that what I know is enough for web programming?

Comment: Consider learning a language that is fundamentally different from C# and VB, a functional language like F# or Haskell. Learning a language like this will make you a better programmer by forcing you to think differently and broadening your horizons.

Answer (score 3):

Other languages are always helpful to broaden your mind as you expand your influence in your career. Knowing how other languages accomplish things gives you useful options in your "home" environment.

Dive into some PHP, or C/C++, or go deep and learn LISP for fun. But don't bother with VB. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's always a good thing to learn new language, new paradigms, new philosophies, new whatever knowledge or way of mind you can find. It will always be useful in a way or another later.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily worry about learning new languages for the sake of learning new languages. You should be aware that other technologies exist and when and where they are used. What's more important is your ability to solve problems and deliver solutions.

Having said that, if you can show you have a basic understanding of other languages it will stand you in good stead, as you won't be starting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn PHP since a lot of the web is written in it

Comment: Should I improve my existing skill in ASP.net or learn PHP, I am confused which would be better.

Comment: I believe it's a lot better if you learn new languages since you colud see how the things you do in some platform can be done in another. Of course I'm not saying forget about .NET and change to PHP. I'm just saying with php you could do more programming to things already written in php like a lot of forums and blogs. For example create a Wordpress theme or pluging for phpBB

Comment: +1 Why the downvotes? This is a legit response. PHP won't bend your mind coming from .NET and JS, but it's not without value as a web engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just generally. If you need to ask this question, then the question *should* be **which one**, not whether there should be one.

F# is within your stable, but sufficiently (i.e. completely) different. Given that you can create assemblies that your web application can dynamically load, I would suggest that you not feel constrained by "web languages".